# Laravel route NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting a new Laravel project, I defined one route and this is my routes.php file

```
 <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('signup', function()
{
    return View::make('signup');
});

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('welcome');
});
```

when I try to load the page `http://localhost/laravel-project/public/signup`
I get a HttpNotFoundException I run artisan routes and the route signup exist. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide more information about your System: - MAMP/ XAMMP
- vhost configuration - and so on ... Then we can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You did create your `signup.blade.php` in the `views` folder?

Comment: unless we get more information from you. Then we will go no where. Start by trying `http://localhost/laravel-project/public/index.php/signup` you might have not properly set the `htaccess`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is from the server because I have another laravel project and it is working correctly

Comment: I created signup.blade.php under the view folder

Comment: Did you look at the log File for further information??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NotFoundHttpException exception is, 100% of the time, Laravel not being able to, somehow, find your route. So, there are some thing you need to be sure are working fine:

1) Check if your VirtualHosts are well configured. By trying to access with `public` in your URL:

```
http://localhost/laravel-project/public/signup
```

I can tell that something is wrong in there, because if you really had your virtualhost well configured, you should not be able to have access to your app folder and this should be your home:

```
http://localhost/laravel-project/
```

And then your signup route would have to be in:

```
http://localhost/laravel-project/signup
```

So, basically your virtualhost should point your root to the public folder, removing the need of it in your urls.

2) Check your `.htaccess` rewriting rules. Can you access your route by using one of those?:

```
http://localhost/laravel-project/public/index.php/signup
```

or

```
http://localhost/laravel-project/index.php/signup
```

If your `.htaccess` file is not in place or if you don't have the rewrite module installed or enabled, it will work, but they shouldn't, unless you want them to work this way. But this is also something that my give you a NotFoundHttpException, because you are not querying your `public/index.php` file, which is, basically, your application boostrapper.